# Extreme values for F-statistic

Tags: statistical-significance, panel-data

I have a question regarding my data. It appears that I have extremely large values of the F statistics, ranging from 20 to 20,000. How is this possible? 
I should mention that it is panel data, controlled for fixed effects as well as clustering.

Comment: It appears as if your null hypothesis is not true. Or your model may be misspecified. Could you clarify the context in which you are calculating F statistics?

Comment: I have seen this when the linear model was fitted without intercept term with the response that was not zero-centered. In such case the obtained model is compared not with "average-response" null-model, but with "zero-response" null-model.

Comment: In addition to the point above, the F-statistic is also a function of the sample size. If you have a huge data set then high F-statistics are not surprising.

Comment: @Erik: is it? The F _statistic_ should not be affected by sample size - only the _p value_ (via the degrees of freedom). Or am I mistaken? (Of course, all this depends on how false the null hypothesis is.)

Comment: I agree with @StephanKolassa effect size measures like F are not affected by sample size. If anything, a huge F for a large data set is *more* surprising.

Comment: One way it could happen is if your model is overfit. But, like others, I think you need to give us more details of what your data was, what your model was, and so on.

Comment: ...maybe I am talking about the wrong F-statistic? But I don't think so. Remember that in linear regression the F-statistic is just the square of the t-statistic and I hope you all agree that this depends on sample size? Too put it more exactly in the F-statistic you have a denominator which depends on the number of groups and which converges to a fixed number as the sample size increases and a numerator which increases linear in the number of samples.

Comment: In addition to $H_0$ not being true, it seems you have quite the highly powered analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with 20 observations in each of three independent treatment groups.
Summary statistics and boxplots are as follows:

```
Descriptive Statistics: A, B, C 

Group      N     Mean  SE Mean  StDev  Minimum      Q1  Median      Q3  Maximum
A         20    18.91     1.16   5.18     7.20   15.75   18.20   23.52    27.30
B         20    38.97     0.95   4.26    30.30   36.45   39.65   42.55    45.80
C         20   119.23     1.17   5.23   106.80  116.62  119.85  123.60   127.40
```

[image]

This is a standard one-factor ANOVA with three levels of the factor.
Because the sample means are quite different and the sample standard deviations
are relatively small, it turns out that the F-statistic is very large, which makes the P-value
essentially 0. (Computations from Minitab 17; format slightly edited for brevity.)

```
Analysis of Variance

Source  DF      SS       MS  F-Value  P-Value
Factor   2  112729  56364.6  2335.42    0.000
Error   57    1376     24.1
Total   59  114105
```

I simulated the data as normal with population means 20, 40, and 120, respectively, and with common population standard deviation 5. So the
one-way ANOVA model is the correct one to test $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B = \mu_C$
against the alternative that not all population means are equal. The null
hypothesis is rejected at any reasonable significance level.

I chose the
data in this way precisely because I knew they would illustrate that
a legitimate F-statistic can be unusually large.

However, @StephanKolassa's warning to check that you have the correct model
for *your* data is important. *Whenever* a P-value is unexpectedly very near $0$
or very near $1,$ it is a good idea to consider once more whether you have the correct model.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

It appears as if your null hypothesis is not true. Or your model may be misspecified. Could you clarify the context in which you are calculating F statistics? – Stephan Kolassa

I have seen this when the linear model was fitted without intercept term with the response that was not zero-centered. In such case the obtained model is compared not with "average-response" null-model, but with "zero-response" null-model. – O_Devinyak

One way it could happen is if your model is overfit. But, like others, I think you need to give us more details of what your data was, what your model was, and so on. – Peter Flom