# F-statistic value is too high for my model

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, p-value, panel-data

> Number of obs     =       501
>   , Method: Fixed-effects regression
>   Number of groups  =       101
>
> > F( 10,   100)     =   3422.31
> >
> > > , Prob > F          =    0.0000
> > >       ,  within R-squared  =    0.6325

My model (panel data with fixed effects) has six variables and four dummies for five years and as you see above, the F-value is too high with a value of 3422. Is this normal? Or what could be the problem?

I should also mention that when I add one variable to the six, the f stat turn from 3422 to 86. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: See [Peter Flom's comment on a similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44709/extreme-values-for-f-statistic?rq=1#comment86796_44709)

Comment: That would be an easy one to look up for yourself. We have plenty of questions related to overfitting. One of the best ways to get better at statistics is to read.

Comment: it seems that you didn't read my question very well because my problem is the F stat of the whole model not for each variable. thanks anyway for passing by

Comment: AFAIK there is no *F* stat for each variable in a single regression model. Single-factor *F*-tests can be performed in ANOVA, which is also a GLM, but I don't think I misunderstood you.

Comment: I am using panel data regression not ANOVA and that was the question you post in your comment

Comment: If the question I linked is about ANOVA *F*-tests and not the regression *F*-test, that's not clear, nor should it matter. The point is that overfitting is a good guess as to a possible problem (if there really is any), especially in regression.

Comment: What is your basis for saying the F value is 'too high'?

Comment: if the model is overfit and I add a variable and run the model again, would that rise or lower the f stat in your opinion ? @NickStauner

Comment: isn't it high dear @Glen_b?
when I run the same model with replacing the dependent variable, the F stat is around 200 only

Comment: You said 'too high'. My question relates to the use of 'too', as if it has crossed some boundary of acceptability. Where does that come from? As to whether it's more generally high or not, it depends on a number of things - why would you expect that it should be some particular value? Why would a different F-statistic give you a basis for judging this one to be excessive, or even merely surprising?

Comment: Whether another variable raises or lowers the model's *F* should depend on whether that variable is related to the outcome in your sample. Since the sixth lowered it in your case, I'm guessing that's a bad predictor, but I can't do more than guess with so little info – I'm not the best statistician around either!

Comment: I don't actually expect any specific value and I said too high because I have about six models more with f stat less than 350 and I thought this f stat high since it is the smallest model. besides that, I didn't face any study with such high f stat value. thanks @Glen_b

Comment: @Nick The sixth might even be quite a good predictor ... but if it's highly correlated with some combination of predictors already in the model, may add very little to their combined explanatory power.

Comment: Even when I add more variables the f get less and I have a doubt that the reason could be the standard error robust type because when I remove the robust or use another one, the value is not as high

Comment: Or when I remove one year of the year dummies the f stat turns to 37 !

Comment: sorry dear @Glen_b, did you find any similar f stat value ?

Comment: I've seen far larger F values. I've seen larger changes in F-value. I suggest not focusing too heavily on the exact values of the F's (a more useful question if you're worried about big changes is how the relevant fitted values compare). I also suggest giving close attention to @NickStauner 's comments.